# Cell of a String array and String doesn't match

Tags: java, android, string, arrays

here's my java code:

```
String s="foo";

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
if(myArray[i]==s)
return true;
```

By debugging, i'm sure that the first element of myArray is the same as my string s, but they doesn't match, because the program jump over the if block(the condition is false). Is there anyone that can help me? Thanks

Comment: "By debugging, I'm sure the first element of `myArray` is the same..." what do you mean by same? Equal content? Same reference? You should investigate this a bit further and refine the question, with things that you have tried.

Comment: sorry is my first experience with java and my first question in StackOverflow. Equal content, i meant. I resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `string.equals()` to compare types of `String`.

```
if(myArray[i]==s)
```

Should be

```
if(myArray[i].equals(s)) {
}
```

At the moment, you're testing if `s` and `myArray[i]` are the same object, not different objects containing the same value.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(myArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase(s))
```